# Manipulating List<Foo> in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

I have the following code which *seems* to be working as expected, but wanted to confirm if anyone has done similar and that I am in fact getting the behavior I think I'm getting.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class SomeWebFormsAspxCodeBehind : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public List<Foo> Foos
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session["MyFoos"] == null)
                Session["MyFoos"] = new List<Foo>();

            return (List<Foo>)Session["MyFoos"];
        }
        set
        {
            Session["MyFoos"] = value;
        }
    }

    public void AddItemToListInSession(Foo foo)
    {
        this.Foos.Add(foo);
    }
}
```

This code seems to be working, I'm binding the `Foos` to a dataview source and getting my expected results.

But are there any "gotchas" I need to be on the lookout for when storing a `List` in `Session`?  How does all functionality of `List` (like `.Add`) continue to work when the list is in `Session`?  Is this behavior abstracted away in `List` or `Session` or a combination of both?

Comment: You have nothing to worry about, When you get it from `Session` object, list has exactly the same functionality as list you stored. Not sure why you think otherwise.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi it just seems like magic... I don't innately trust magic :P

Comment: If your question is _"What happens when storing an object in the session and then retrieving it?"_, then I suggest you start reading about the session and serialization. Depending on the session storage being used, the object is actually serialized and deserialized. Functionality (such as methods that you can call) does not reside in an object, they reside in the type.